# NodeJS response.end when promise finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a tough time dealing with promises in nodeJS.

What I want to accomplish is to translate an HTML page with Google Translate API. The HTML document is sent to my nodeJS server. I use jquery to send every chunk to the API and then replace the translated content.

The problem is that the server returns the response before the content is translated because the call to the API is asynchronous.

I need to translate it, replace it and ONLY then return the content.

My non-working code is the following:

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var http = require('http');
const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate');
var testStr;

var httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
    
    let buffer = '';
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        buffer += decoder.write(chunk);
    });
    
    req.on('end', () => {
        buffer += decoder.end();
        testStr = buffer;
        var jsdom = require("jsdom");
        var { JSDOM } = jsdom;
        var myhtml = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body>"+testStr+"</body></html>";
        var { window } = new JSDOM( myhtml );
        var $ = require( "jquery" )( window );
        el = window.document;
        
        $("*").each(async function(){
            if($(this).is("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,blockquote")){
                var toBeTranslated = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
                var translatedChunk = await GoogleTranslateText(toBeTranslated);
                $(this).replaceWith(translatedChunk);
            }
        });
        
        translated = el.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].innerHTML;
        res.writeHead(200, 'OK', { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
        res.end(translated);
    });
    
    async function GoogleTranslateText(toBeTranslated) {
      // Construct request
      const request = {
        parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
        contents: [toBeTranslated],
        mimeType: 'text/html', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
        sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
        targetLanguageCode: 'pl',
      };

      try {
        // Run request
        const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

        for (const translation of response.translations) {
          return translation.translatedText;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.details);
        return false;
      }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use this?

Replace:

```
$("*").each(async function(){
            if($(this).is("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,blockquote")){
                var toBeTranslated = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
                var translatedChunk = await GoogleTranslateText(toBeTranslated);
                $(this).replaceWith(translatedChunk);
            }
        });
```

with the below:

```
await Promise.all($("*").map(async function(){
   if($(this).is("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,blockquote")){
       var toBeTranslated = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
       var translatedChunk = await GoogleTranslateText(toBeTranslated);
       $(this).replaceWith(translatedChunk);
   }
}).get());
```

Comment: I also added async to req.on('end',async () => {

Answer (score 0):

Your response is returned before the promises are resolved. Use **Promise.all()** to wait until the promises are resolved and then send the response

You could do something like this.

```
const promiseArray = [];
       
 $("*").each(async function(){
    if($(this).is("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,blockquote")){
        var toBeTranslated = $(this)[0].outerHTML;

        // push the promises to the array
        promiseArray.push(GoogleTranslateText(toBeTranslated));
     }
    });
    
   Promise.all(promiseArray).then(res=>{
      // Do the replacement and then send the response
        translated = el.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].innerHTML;
        res.writeHead(200, 'OK', { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
        res.end(translated);
    })
```